Splunk Query to fetch the data for API and respective response code with success and failure for yesterday
index="db"  "Market"=Country_name  getsim Postsim getset
| rename ResultCode as RC 
| eval Status = case(like(RC, "200"),"Error") 
| timechart span=1d count(Status) as total, count(eval(Status="Failure")) as Failure,count(eval(Status="Success")) as Success, count(eval(Status="Error")) as Error 
| eval percent_failure=round(((Failure/total)*100),2) 
| eval percent_ok=round(((Success/total)*100),2) 
| eval percent_error=round(((Error/total)*100),2) 
| fields - total 
| rename percent_error as Error, percent_ok as Success, percent_failure as Failure 
| fields _time Failure Error Success

i wants the data in below format for yesterday, however API can vary in my query so Query need to produce result with API and their respone code with success and failure %
API     Response Code  Success% Failure%
getsim   200            99%      1%
getsim    400            80       20
postsim   200            99%      2%
postsim    400           80       20
I require to create dashboard with the help of this query.

How do the current results differ from the results you want?

I agree with @RichG What is your end goal here?  Is your query not giving you the right answer? Do you need to save it as just a dashboard? Do you need a table?
